# How to get the calculated time in a timepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have this timepicker plugin from https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker and I want to get the calculated time and put it in a input field. Any help? 
See http://postimg.org/image/4m78gqdmx/ for image reference. 
How to get the calculated time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.val()` to get the time.

Comment: What I mean is ho can I get the CALCULATED TIME? See postimg.org/image/4m78gqdmx I want to get (1.5hrs) for example

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Event Example" at their page that should help

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

```
$('#onselectExample').timepicker();
$('#onselectExample').on('changeTime', function() {
    $('#onselectTarget').text($(this).val());
});
```

Where `$('#onselectTarget')` could be anything from a `<div>` or a `<span>` to an `<input>` field. Just remember to set `.text()` or `.val()` accordingly.

In the above example, they set the inner text of a `span` to the value of the timepicker on change. If you want to set the value of another input field, you can change it to:

```
$('#onselectExample').timepicker();
$('#onselectExample').on('changeTime', function() {
    $('#onselectTarget').val($(this).val());
});
```

(notice the `.val()` instead of `.text()`)

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, the question was about calculated time, not the actual time. Here is one possible solution.

This isn't pretty, since there is no build in functionality to return the calculated time on change, but it should work

http://jsfiddle.net/9ya53/

```
$('#onselectExample').timepicker({
    'minTime': '2:00pm',
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'showDuration': true
});
$('#onselectExample').on('changeTime', function() {
    $('#onselectTarget').val($("li:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").find('.ui-timepicker-duration').text());
});
```

Comment: What I mean is how can I get the `CALCULATED TIME?` See http://postimg.org/image/4m78gqdmx/ I want to get `(1.5hrs)` for example

Comment: There is no native way of achieving this with timepicker, but I updated my answer with a possible solution at the bottom.

Comment: So how can I do that with `2 timepicker`?

Comment: I mean I have a timepicker with `start time` and `end time` and I want to get the total time from the `start time` to `end time` please + 1

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle, or update mine, so that I can see exactly what it is you are trying to do.